# AWS SDK s3 Assume Role Provider `403 Forbidden` response

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am following the AWS SDK guide here

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials_provider.html

I followed the instructions to create an instance Profile for EC2

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-iam-instance-profile.html#getting-started-create-iam-instance-profile-console

I copied the code from here.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials_provider.html

Here is my modified code.

```
// Passing Aws\Credentials\AssumeRoleCredentialProvider options directly
$profile = new InstanceProfileProvider();
$ARN = "arn:aws:iam::645648943563:role/InstancePermissionOpenEMR";
$sessionName = "s3-access-openemr";

$assumeRoleCredentials = new AssumeRoleCredentialProvider([
    'client' => new StsClient([
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
        'version' => 'latest',
        'credentials' => $profile
    ]),
    'assume_role_params' => [
        'RoleArn' => $ARN,
        'RoleSessionName' => $sessionName,
    ],
]);

// To avoid unnecessarily fetching STS credentials on every API operation,
// the memoize function handles automatically refreshing the credentials when they expire
$provider = CredentialProvider::memoize($assumeRoleCredentials);

$client = new S3Client([
    'region'      => 'us-east-1',
    'version'     => 'latest',
    'credentials' => $provider
]);

function createBucket($client, $bucketName): string
{
    try {
        $result = $client->createBucket([
            'Bucket' => $bucketName,
        ]);
        return 'The bucket\'s location is: ' .
            $result['Location'] . '. ' .
            'The bucket\'s effective URI is: ' .
            $result['@metadata']['effectiveUri'];
    } catch (AwsException $e) {
        return 'Error: ' . $e->getAwsErrorMessage();
    }
}

function createTheBucket($client): void
{
    echo createBucket($client, 'acetestbucket');
}

// Uncomment the following line to run this code in an AWS account.
createTheBucket($client);
```

This throws and error.

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://sts.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
```

Why is this error being thrown? I have not found any postings anywhere that address this

Comment: What does it say further in the error message?

Comment: A lot here you can see for yourself. https://sites.affordablecustomehr.com/interface/modules/custom_modules/oe-simple-storage-solution/public/AssumeRoleProvider.php . My concern is that the guide to create the Role did not provide enough permissions to create an S3 bucket. The only two things that were given is GET* LIST*

Comment: I think this is what you are asking for the Trust Relationship {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: The problem is the entire code is wrong and I had not assigned the role to the EC2. Once I assigned the role to the EC2 and called CredentialProvider::instanceProfile(); Then I was able to get the buckets that are available to the EC2. TaDa!